# Trying to display all records in HTML but it is only presenting last item from the database in the HTML

Tags: python, html, sqlite, flask

This code only outputs the final record in the Sqlite table. It does not output ALL records from the table into the HTML. Any suggestions?

```
import sqlite3    
from flask import Flask, render_template, redirect, request   
app = Flask(__name__)

connection = sqlite3.connect('employee.db')

cur = connection.cursor()
cur.execute('SELECT * FROM employee;')
s = "<table style='border:2px solid black'>"
for row in cur:    
    s = s + "<tr>"    
for x in row:    
    s = s + "<td>" + str(x) + "</td>"    
    s = s + "</tr>"    
cur.close()

@app.route('/')  
def main():    

    return "<html><body>" + s + "</body></html>" 

if __name__ == "__main__": 
    app.run()
```

Comment: you could try `for row in cur.fetchall()` but iirc `for row in cur` should work... but i could be wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nest the second `for x in row` loop in the `for row in cur` loop to make sure it is run for every `row`

This should solve your problem.

```py
import sqlite3    
from flask import Flask, render_template, redirect, request   
app = Flask(__name__)

connection = sqlite3.connect('employee.db')

cur = connection.cursor()
cur.execute('SELECT * FROM employee;')
s = "<table style='border:2px solid black'>"
for row in cur:    
    s += "<tr>"    
    for x in row:    
        s += "<td>" + str(x) + "</td>"    
        s += "</tr>"    
cur.close()


@app.route('/')  
def main():    
    return "<html><body>" + s + "</body></html>" 


if __name__ == "__main__": 
    app.run()
```